# How Can I Draw Proper Audio Waveform against Playing Audio File From Live Url?

Tags: ios, ios7

[image]enter image description hereI'm using this EZAudio Library from the Following link[EZAudio Library which help to draw wave form on base audio file](https://github.com/syedhali/EZAudio)

but it doesn't support anyone can help me and how can i use it to draw audio wave form with my FSAudio streamer . i want to make proper audio wave form like this picture. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to provide more detail. What is FSAudio streamer? How is the audio getting into your application? What format? etc

Comment: FSAudio Streamer is actually audio streamer api from github link [link](https://github.com/muhku/FreeStreamer) and format of audio file is mp3.

Comment: in this library FSFrequencyDomainAnalyzer and FSFrequencyPlotView classes are used to plot audio wave . Which is not according to my requirement.

Comment: Your Post title is misleading, as for what you want to do, well you have source code for both, streaming and drawing waveforms. Roll up your sleeves and poke through the code, seemingly you are looking for someone to do the work for you. That's not the purpose of SO, if you've made an attempt post code and others might help.

Comment: did you found any solution?

Comment: No, I didn't found any proper solution @KD4